# SUM of only TOP 10 rows

Tags: sql, sum, top-n

I have a query where I am only selecting the TOP 10 rows, but I have a SUM function in there that is still taking the sum of all the rows (disregarding the TOP 10). How do I get the total of only the top 10 rows?
Here is my SUM function :

```
SUM( fact.Purchase_Total_Amount) Total
```

Comment: The answer to this is going to be dependent on which DBMS you use (e.g., in SQL Server you would use `TOP`, in MySQL `LIMIT`, in Oracle `ROWNUM` or the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function). Perhaps you might copy and paste the query you're using to get the top 10 rows?

Comment: Sorry, this is SQL server. This is the first part of the query: `SELECT 
top 10
itmf.Table_Name
,SUM( fact.Purchase_Total_Amount) Total
,(SUM(fact.Purchase_Total_Amount)/

(SELECT SUM(Purchase_Total_Amount) FROM
TableName fact
join TableName2 .....`

Answer (score 25):

Have you tried to use something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Whatever)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(10) Whatever
    FROM TableName
) AS T
```

Comment: So the TOP 10 statement should be within the nested query? inside the nested query is my function for calculating percentage and that didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Have you tried? As far as i can see (in your comments), you do that in a different way.

Comment: Note that the "AS T" is not an optional part of the syntax (at least in MSSQL)

Answer (score 3):

Use the TOP feature with a nested query

```
SELECT SUM(innerTable.Purchase_Total_Amount) FROM
(SELECT TOP 10 Purchase_Total_Amount FROM Table) as innerTable
```